# mySQL asp role provider error. Unable to connect to SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, mysql

This is my first attempt at doing roles for asp.net, what I have is a mySQL backend, and I want to add a bunch of roles to a user.  The code i'm using below, i keep getting the error Unable to connect to SQL Server database.  I'm assuming this is because the default provider refers to SQL, but i'm not able to figure out how to switch it so I can add multiple roles to a user.  Thanks for the help!

```
using (MySqlConnection cn2 = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=users; User=root;Password=PASSWORD;"))
            {
                cn2.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(storedProcedureName2, cn);
                cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@usernameID", userID);
                MySqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr2.Read())
                {
                    string roleName = dr2["role"].ToString();
                    Roles.AddUserToRole(userID, roleName);
                }


            }
```

Comment: thats not your real password, is it? Changed it anyway....

Comment: when do you get the error. On the cmd2.Excecute or on the Roles.AddUserToRole

Comment: on the Roles.AddUserToRole and no it's the dev pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the ASP.NET Membership and roles in the web.config file. Something like this would set your default provider to a MySQL backend:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MySqlMembershipProvider">
<providers>
<clear />
<add name="MySqlMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySqlMembershipProvider,M ySql.Web,Version=6.3.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" autogenerateschema="true" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requireQuestionAndAnswer="false" requireUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="0" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" applicationName="/" />
</providers>
</membership>
<profile defaultProvider="MySqlProfileProvider">
<providers>
<clear/>
<add name="MySqlProfileProvider" type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.3.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" conectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/"/>
</providers>
</profile>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MySqlRoleProvider">
<providers>
<clear/>
<add connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" name="MySqlRoleProvider"
type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.3.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
</providers>
</roleManager>
<trust level="Full"/>
<machineKey validationKey="AutoGenerate" validation="SHA1"/>
```

EDIT: I added the connectionStrings section below:

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalMySqlServer"/>
    <add name="LocalMySqlServer" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=users; User=root;Password=PASSWORD;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: i think i get what you're doing but that is giving me a lot of trouble

Comment: If you are still getting the error, can you move the connection string to the web.config like I did above, and make sure the connectionStringName attribute of your Role Provider is using it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following as the connection string:

```
 "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=users;Uid=root;Pwd=PASSWORD;"
```

And if it works, change the password :)

If this doesn't work, and assuming the error is in the connecting ot the database (you confused my by publishing so many lines of code) do the usual checks:

- Is the server running?
- Is the password correct
- Is the port default (3306)
- Are there internal firewall issues, as MySQL uses TCP:3306 and in theory firewall can block this.